# SceneKit switch between scene memory leak

Tags: swift, memory-leaks, scenekit

I have two blank scnscene objects without any nodes and cameras:

```
func setupScenes() {
   scnView = SCNView(frame: self.view.frame)
   self.view.addSubview(scnView)

   gameScene = SCNScene(named: "/MrPig.scnassets/GameScene.scn")
   splashScene = SCNScene(named: "/MrPig.scnassets/SplashScene.scn")
   scnView.scene = splashScene
}
```

Two methods for displaying each scnscene:

```
func startSplash() {
    gameScene.isPaused = true
    let transition = SKTransition.doorsOpenVertical(withDuration: 1.0)
    scnView.present(splashScene, with: transition, incomingPointOfView: nil, completionHandler: {
      self.gameState = .tapToPlay
      self.setupSounds()
      self.splashScene.isPaused = false
    })
  }

  func startGame() {
    splashScene.isPaused = true
    let transition = SKTransition.doorsOpenVertical(withDuration: 1.0)
    scnView.present(gameScene, with: transition, incomingPointOfView: nil, completionHandler: {
      self.gameState = .playing
      self.setupSounds()
      self.gameScene.isPaused = false
    })
  }
```

And touch gesture for switching between scnscenes:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if gameState == .tapToPlay {
            startGame()
        } else {
            startSplash()
        }
    }
```

Each time I touch the screen first or second scnscene appears on the screen and I got used plus ~80Mb of RAM.
After 10 times touching 500MB of RAM already used.

I don't understand why it happens?

Comment: Better to check Memory Graph or Profiler to find the real culprit.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious problem in your code is that every time you call startGame() and startSplash()methods, the nested function with closure capturing your "self" with strong reference.

> Some info about strong and weak references and [ARC](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html).

First, you should do the following:

```
func startSplash() {
    gameScene.isPaused = true
    let transition = SKTransition.doorsOpenVertical(withDuration: 1.0)
    scnView.present(splashScene, with: transition, incomingPointOfView: nil, completionHandler: { [weak self] in
        guard let self = self else { return }
        self.gameState = .tapToPlay
        self.setupSounds()
        self.splashScene.isPaused = false
    })
}

func startGame() {
    splashScene.isPaused = true
    let transition = SKTransition.doorsOpenVertical(withDuration: 1.0)
    scnView.present(gameScene, with: transition, incomingPointOfView: nil, completionHandler: { [weak self] in
        guard let self = self else { return }
        self.gameState = .playing
        self.setupSounds()
        self.gameScene.isPaused = false
    })
}
```

Second, try not to use touchesBegan method it could lead to some side effects.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem and could not spot the reason, but I guess it has something to do with spritekit, specially when you use metal and scenekit alongside each other. see [scenekit spritekit memory leak](https://github.com/gsabran/SceneKit-SpriteKit-memoryLeak).
present(scene...) is from spritekit. the only solution i come up with was set scene and pointofview of SCNView directly, not through present(...) method.